# $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that all points in $X$ are isolated $\implies$ $X^{'}$ enumerable

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> Prove or disprove: $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that all points in $X$ are isolated $\implies$ $X^{'}$ enumerable

I need resolve it in order to solve another question, but even this seems simples i couldn't resolve.

My attempt(**I hope this is true**): Let $S$ be the set of convergent sequences in $X$.
Define:
$f \colon X^{'} \to S$, for each $x \in X^{'}$,  $f(x) \in S$ is a sequence that converges to $x$.

Is easy to see that $f$ is injective, so I want to find a bijection $\phi \colon f(X^{'}) \to X$ injective, using that $f(x)$ is a sequence of islated points in $X$. I didn't find $\phi$.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What is the relationship between $X'$ and $X$ ?

Comment: Define X',I'm baffled.

Comment: possibly but an answer would not be out of the way

Comment: $X^{'}$ is the set of limit points of $X$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you’re trying to prove is false. Let

$$X=\left\{\left\langle\frac{2m+1}{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\right\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\text{ and }m\in\Bbb Z\right\}\;;$$

every point of $X$ is isolated in $X$, but $X'$ is the whole $x$-axis.

**Added:** For that matter, you could just as well use the simpler set

$$\left\{\left\langle\frac{m}{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\right\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\text{ and }m\in\Bbb Z\right\}\;,$$

for which the convergence to the $x$-axis may be a little easier to see. $X$ is a subset of it that has at most one point on each vertical line.

Comment: What is $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ here?

Comment: @Ahmed: An ordered pair. It’s an alternative standard notation that I prefer, since parentheses already have enough other uses.

Comment: I should have known that; it's not uncommon and this is the only way it can make sense here. I guess I was confused because I misread the question. Anyway, very nice example.

Comment: @Ahmed: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one, in $\mathbb R$.

$X = $ the set of midpoints of the complementary intervals of the Cantor set.  So every point of $X$ is the midpoint of an interval with no other points of $X$; that is every point is isolated.  But $X'$ is the Cantor set, uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: all point of $X$ are isolated i.e there exists open balls $B_x(x,r_x>0)$ with $B(x,r_x)\cap B(y,r_y)$ is empty if $x\neq y$. Take an element $q_x\in Q^n\cap B(x,r_x)$ an define $f:X\rightarrow Q^n f(x)=q_x$. Use the fact that $Q^n$ is numerable and $f$ is injective.

Remark.

A point $x$ is isolated if there is a ball $B(x,r_x)$ such that $B(x,r_x)\cap X=\{x\}$ this is equivalent here (in $R^n$) that you can suppose for every $x$ that $B(x,r_x)\cap B(y,r_y)$ is empty for some $r_y$ if $x\neq y$ otherwise there is $z_n\in B(x,1/n)\cap B(y_n,1/n), y_n\in X, y_n\neq x$ which implies that  $(y_n),$ converges towards $x$ since $d(x,y_n)\leq d(x,z_n)+d(z_n,y_n)\leq {1\over {2n}}$.

Comment: $f$ need not be 1-1 the way you've set things up

Comment: Also let $r_x\in {\mathbb Q}$ and we have got the enumeration

Comment: Your map $x\to f(x)$ need not be injective. Example: $S=\{0,1\}.$ Then $B(0,1)\cap X = \{0\}, B(1,1)\cap X = \{1\}.$ Then we have $1/2\in B(0,1)\cap B(1,1).$ Since we are at liberty to choose any rational we want in these balls, we can set $f(0) = 1/2 = f(1).$ This $f$ is not injective.

Comment: For me isolated means you can choose the balls such that $B(x,r_x)\cap B(y,r_y)$ is empty if $x\neq y$.

Comment: Well that's not the definition. It needs to be shown.

Comment: I don't know your definition of isolated point, but it means you have a ball $B(x,r_x)$ such that $B(x,r_x)\cap X=\{x\}$ this trivially is equivalent here (in $R^n$) that you can suppose for every $x$ that $B(x,r_x)\cap B(y,r_y)$ is empty for some $r_y$ if $x\neq y$ otherwise there is $z_n\in B(x,1/n)\cap B(y_n,1/n), y_n\in X$ and $(y_n), y_n\neq x$ converges towards $x$ since $d(x,y_n)\leq d(x,z_n)+d(z_n,y_n)\leq {1\over {2n}}$.

Comment: Yes, for each fixed $x$ you can do that. But that doesn't prove what you have claimed.